# Can I refinance a rental property that is currently only 75% loan to value?

Tags: real-estate, refinance, rental-property

I have two separate rental properties that each have a LTV of about 75%.  I'd like to leverage these properties to buy another investment or rental property so I am considering refinancing with cash out.

I am having trouble finding a lender that will work with my scenario in the current financial environment even with my excellent credit rating.  Can anyone recommend a lender?

Can anyone recommend another method of leveraging the equity I have to allow for further investing?

Answer (score 2):

I have been shopping around for a refi on my rental property. All of the programs are 75% LTV that I have found. This appears to be the new reality that we are in. Therefore, you won't be able to get that last 25% out.

I did get a great rate from Wells Fargo today at 5.25% for a rental refi cashout but it will be a 75% LTV.